# Groovy execute "cp *" shell command

Tags: groovy

I want to copy text files and only text files from `src/` to `dst/`

```
groovy:000> "cp src/*.txt dst/".execute().text       
===> 
groovy:000>
```

You can see the command executes w/out error but the file `src/test.txt` does not get copied to `dst/`

This also fails:

```
groovy:000> "cp src/* dst/".execute().text       
===> 
groovy:000>
```

However...

```
"cp src/this.txt dst/".execute().text
```

works

Also,

```
"cp -R src/ dst".execute().text
```

works

Why dose the wild card seem to cause my command to silently fail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wildcard expansion is performed by the shell, not by cp (or groovy).  Your first example is trying to copy a file named *.  You could make your command "sh -c 'cp ...'"

Answer (score 17):

Thanks tedu for getting me half way there.

I believe the reason that his solution didn't work was because of an 'escaping' issue.

For instance...

```
"sh -c 'ls'".execute()
```

works. But...

```
"sh -c 'ls '".execute()
```

does not.

There is probably a way to escape it properly in line there but the workaround I'm using is to pass a string array to Runtime.getRuntime().exec

```
command = ["sh", "-c", "cp src/*.txt dst/"]
Runtime.getRuntime().exec((String[]) command.toArray())
```

works beautifully!

Comment: I think you could simplify that with:

    command = ....
    command.execute()

As arrays also understand execute

Comment: The reason that `"sh -c 'cp src/*.txt dst/''"` does not work is because Groovy will interpret a quoted string argument with whitespace as multiple arguments.  So groovy is actually executing sh with the following args: 
arg1 = -c, arg2 = 'cp, arg3 = src/*.txt, arg4 = dst/' Such a command  will result in an "Unterminated quoted string" error.  You have the correct solution, which is to use an array. Also, @TimM is right, you can simplify the above to `["sh", "-c", "cp src/*.txt dst/"].execute()`

Comment: If you're building your commands dynamically the solution with sh -c and an array is the best solution. Just do:
def command = (generate command here)
def proc = ["sh", "-c", command].execute()

Comment: I still get "*.png: No such file or directory" when using `["sh", "-c", "cp *.png dest/"].execute()`.