# Can I use wild cards when executing a shell process in a different working directory?

Tags: groovy

This is my current directory structure

```
/ <-- current working Dir
  /php/
    file1.php
    file2.php
    file3.txt
```

I am trying to execute the following groovy commands

```
def cp = 'cp -f *.php /tmp/'
def cpProc = cp.execute(null, new File('./php/')
cpProc.waitfor()
log.info 'current exitvalue :' + cpProc.exitValue()
log.info 'current proc out : ' + cpProc.text
```

but I keep getting `cp: cannot stat *.php': No such file or directory`, I've verified the files exist and I've verified my current working directory

if I execute `log.info 'ls -la'.execute(null, new File('./php/'))` I see the PHP and .txt files.

This seems like a long shot but I think there might be a bug with using wild cards for commands when executing them in a specified working directory, unless there's something I'm missing?

I'm using groovy 1.7.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this version works for me, just try it out:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env groovy

    command = ["sh", "-c", "cp -f *.php /tmp/"]
    def cpProc = command.execute(null, new File('./php/'))
    cpProc.waitFor()
    print 'current exitvalue :' + cpProc.exitValue() + '\n'
    print 'current proc out : ' + cpProc.text + '\n'

    print 'ls -la'.execute(null, new File('/tmp/')).text
```

The first answer on this question explains why your version did not work: [Groovy execute "cp *" shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183352/groovy-execute-cp-shell-command)